# Collections.unmodifiable* как определить?

Tags: java, коллекции

Известно, что есть класс `java.util.Collections` в котором есть методы вида `unmodifiable*` возвращающие *неизменяемые* коллекции. Теперь вопрос, как определить, что коллекция является неизменяемой?

Comment: В виде хаков: а) Ловить `UnsupportedOperationException` при добавлении элемента, б) `.getClass().getSimpleName().equals(...)`. Каноническое решение вряд ли найдете.

Comment: ну я тоже к этому склонялся, думал может кто знает красивее решение.

Comment: а зачем это может понадобиться знать? Если какой-то API возвращает неизменяемую коллекцию это стоит явно оговаривать.

Comment: @Nofate есть библиотека сериализующая объекты в byte[] и обратно. у объекта могут быть поля такого типа? да могут. но в процессе дисериализации, когда создается инстанс данной коллекции и происходит попытка добавления туда элемента, возникает исключение. Пытаюсь сделать проверку как раз для данного случая

Comment: В данном случае неправа библиотека. При десериализации должна десериализовываться исходная коллекция как поле неизменяемого класса, и не должно быть никаких вызовов типа `add()`.

Comment: согласен, но переписать всю библиотеку я не смогу, а сделать проверку  мне под силу.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Какое-либо универсальное *хорошее* решение Вы вряд ли найдете.

На мой взгляд, самое некостыльное из костылей – `.getClass().isInstance(...)`:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
List<String> unmodifiableList = Collections.unmodifiableList(list);
boolean isUnmodifiable = Collections.unmodifiableList(list).getClass().isInstance(unmodifiableList);
```

Еще варианты:

1. Ловить `UnsupportedOperationException` при добавлении элемента. Но тогда, в случае изменяемой коллекции, после теста элемент нужно удалить.
2. `.getClass().getSimpleName().equals(...)`.